# What's the sex tag mean?

Tags: discussion, tags

Inspired by its use in this question: [My son has been offered money by a classmate, if he would pull down his underwear](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/19144/my-son-has-been-offered-money-by-a-classmate-if-he-would-pull-down-his-underwea)

[sex](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex) Doesn't have a description, and it's used to cover a variety of sexual-issues:

- Sexual intercourse for parents
- Teen children interested in sex
- Masturbation
- Childhood sex play
- Events that may have been sexual in nature
- Sexuality and sexual orientation
- Sex education

How should we describe this tag? Should we make more than one, to differentiate between some of these uses?

Will better-described tags help facilitate discussion of these often-more-difficult topics?

---

**Update**

[sex](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex) and [sex-education](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex-education) have had wiki tag edits proposed and accepted.

Comment: I was wondering how the front page was all sex-ed :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop I did that after I posted the update, but I'd meant to do it as soon as the wiki tag went through. I've limited time lately (end of semester!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest that the tag be limited to questions about sex-the-activity, including from your list:

1. Sexual intercourse for parents
2. Teen children interested in sex
3. Masturbation
4. Childhood sex play
5. Events that may have been sexual in nature

But not including:

6. Sexuality and sexual orientation - conevert to [sexual-orientation](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexual-orientation) or similar
7. Sex education - convert to [sex-education](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex-education)

I think the first set will be somewhat unavoidable to all be linked to this tag, though I don't object to also having some more specific tags for a couple of them; since many of these questions will come from newer users, they'll expect [sex](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex) to be applicable, and I think that's okay.

2,3,4 will be covered by age-specific tags as most of those questions are about the same thing at different ages - exploring sexuality - and it's reasonable to link them together (sometimes the same answers apply even at different ages).  5 I don't completely understand, but either will be part of sexual exploration or will be more like sexual abuse or similar (which should get a tag more like [sex-abuse](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex-abuse) if it doesn't already).  1 would also have an 'age specific' tag [parents](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parents).

Comment: 5 is meant to refer to the question linked at the beginning of my question. There *may* have been something sexual going on there.

Comment: Ah, okay.  That question seems clearly related to childhood exploration of sexuality to me so I didn't think of that.

Comment: I have proposed a wiki tag edit for "sex" based on this, and also for "sex-education" (since it already had 1 question).